# AWS DMS Log growth problem - SQL Server as Source

Tags: sql-server, replication, amazon-dms

I have a problem using the AWS Database Migration Service for implementing a transactional replication from SQL Server as a source database engine, a help is highly appreciated.

The '**safeguardPolicy**' connection attribute defaults to '**RELY_ON_SQL_SERVER_REPLICATION_AGENT**'. The tools will start mimicking a transaction in the database for preventing the log to be reused and to be able to read as much changes from the active log.

But what is the intended behavior of these safeguard transaction? Will those sessions be stopped at some point? What is the mechanism to start / run for some time / stop such a transaction?

The production databases I manage are in Full recovery mode, with Log backups on each half an hour. The log grows to an enormous size due to the inability for a valid truncation procedure to succeed and because of those safeguard transactions initiated by the DMS tool.

The only solution to a full transaction log due to LOG_SCAN caused by such behavior of DMS for now is to stop the DMS tasks and run a manual truncation of the log, to release space not used. But it is not a solution at all if we need to stop the replication each time such a problem occurs, knowing that it will occur often.

Please share some internals about the tool if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122978/aws-dms-unable-to-truncate-sql-transaction-log/50812726#50812726

Comment: Hello @YunusUYANIK, according to the documentation, if you use {EXCLUSIVE_AUTOMATIC_TRUNCATION} then only one AWS DMS task can access the database at any given time. We are using DMS to run ongoing replication and we need 10 DMS tasks to run against the same database in parallel. We group tables to be replicated in separate tasks. That's why I didn't go to try that solution. Please correct me if I understand the logic behind that wrong. And thanks a lot for replying!

Comment: If do you use readBackupOnly=Y so  EXCLUSIVE_AUTOMATIC_TRUNCATION this part not for you. You can try only sp_repldone procedure and shrink database because after that you can.